# Sequelize Associations always use lazy loading

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to do some relations and get some data without lazy loading.
Models:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Post extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      Post.belongsTo(models.User);
    }
  }
  Post.init({
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    body: DataTypes.TEXT
  }, {
    indexes: [{unique: true, fields: ['id']}],
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Post',
  });
  return Post;
};
```

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      User.hasMany(models.Post);
    }
  }
  User.init({
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    indexes: [{unique: true, fields: ['id']}],
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

And when I try to query users or posts, there is no information about each other in the nested objects:

```
const getAllPosts = async(req) => {
    try {
        const posts = await Post.findAll({
            includes: [User]
        });
        console.log(posts)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

```
const getAllUsers = async (req) => {
    try {
        return await User.findAll({
            raw: true,
            includes: [Post]
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Console logs: 
**From post service:**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'qwe',
    body: 'qwe',
    createdAt: '2022-03-13 10:59:38.539 +00:00',
    updatedAt: '2022-03-13 10:59:38.551 +00:00',
    UserId: 1
  }
]
```

**From user service:**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Evaldas',
    lastName: 'Doda',
    email: null,
    createdAt: '2022-03-13 10:59:31.425 +00:00',
    updatedAt: '2022-03-13 10:59:31.425 +00:00'
  }
]
```

The problem is that I can create Post with the User, but can't get any data of these in the queries.

Comment: Try `console.log(posts.map(x => x.get{ plain: true }))` instead of `console.log(posts)`

Comment: Maybe not bad solution but how can I use this in render method? I’m using hbs to render pages and I need to pass object to template

Comment: These would be not model instances but plain objects just like you need

Comment: Problem persists, still don't have user object inside.
```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'qwe',
    body: 'qwe',
    createdAt: 2022-03-13T10:59:38.539Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-03-13T10:59:38.551Z,
    UserId: 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You indicated the option `includes` instead of `include`. Just correct the option name and that's it.

```js
 const posts = await Post.findAll({
  include: [User]
 });
```

And still it's better to use `get({ plain: true })` to get plain objects if you plan to pass them outside as a response (for instance).